# React Native fbsdk - How to change Facebook Login Button language/localization?

Tags: facebook, react-native, authentication, locale

I added a Facebook Login button to my app, when logged out, it currently says "Continue with Facebook".

I see a FacebookSDKStrings.bundle file in the FBSDK folder containing the strings used by the button, how can I make my app read them from "es_LA" subfolder? Instead of defaulting to "en_US".

As a note, my device has "es_LA" as the current locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example of making a completely custom button which is a better option anyways.

[Change the FB login button text (react-native-fbsdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850390/change-the-fb-login-button-text-react-native-fbsdk)