# How to center text in Facebook Login Button for React Native (Android)?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fbsdk

I am using Facebook SDK's (via `react-native-fbsdk`) Login Button in my React-Native application.

The button text `Continue with Facebook` appears centered vertically in iOS but is off-center in Android (7.0).

Is my only option to make my own custom button which calls the LoginManager manually, or is there a way to align the text using styles (I tried alignItems and justifyContent)? It seems like I have to do the former based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850390/change-the-fb-login-button-text-react-native-fbsdk?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

This is my code as of now:

```
<LoginButton
   scope={'public_profile email'}
   style={{
       width: 220,
       height: 40
   }}
   onLoginFinished={this._facebookLogin}
   onLogoutFinished={() => console.log('logout.')}
/>
```

[image: Photo of misaligned text]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, gave up on it :/

Comment: Okay I'll post my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the button into a container

```
<View style={{
  width: 220, // whatever you want
  height: 50, // whatever you want
  justifyContent: 'center', // center the button
  backgroundColor: '#4267B2', // the same as the actual button
  paddingHorizontal: 10 // optionally add some horizontal padding for better looking
}}>
  <LoginButton
    scope={'public_profile email'}
    style={{
       flex: 1, // fill the container
       maxHeight: 30 // the default height
   }}
   onLoginFinished={this._facebookLogin}
   onLogoutFinished={() => console.log('logout.')}
  />
</View>
```

The results

[image]

Comment: Going through this nightmare right now. Thanks for this 